# OS X 10.8.2 not supporting Java application

Tags: macos, java, safari

Even with the latest update for Java (JRE 7u9) on my Mac book (OS X 10.8.2), I am unable to run Java applet from Safari. Does anyone have idea why this happening?

PS: Now that I've enabled the Java console, I get the following error:

> coupons.target.com quit unexpectedly while using the libel wast.dylib plug-in

Answer (score 0):

Java has received a lot of heat of recent vulnerabilities and attacks.  Apple has responded by disabling some of the functionality by default.  Please see the following article:

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57414869-263/how-to-use-java-applets-in-os-x-after-java-2012-003-update/